# How to find index of specific object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a list of items:

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="good">first</div>
  <div class="good">second</div>
  <div>trash</div>
  <div class="good">third</div>
</div>
```

and I set a bind:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list").children(".good").click(function () {
        var index = getIndex(this);
        alert(index);
    });
});
```

How may I determine the index of the clicked item such that first would alert 0, second: 1 and third: 2 when clicked on?

I tried something similar to but it returns -1 every time.:

```
function getIndex(obj) {
    var $objectArray = $("#list").children(".good");
    return $.inArray($(obj), $objectArray);
```

Any Ideas?

Oh, Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sh9Dt/

Slight edit to add another garbage list, I need it in relation to a specific jquery select.

**Working JSFiddle thanks to @adeneo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Sh9Dt/1/

Comment: Use the `index` method, `$(this).index()`.

Comment: You're trying to make something that jQuery already has built in, just do `var index = $("#list").children().index(this)`

Comment: @adeneo That's what I was looking for. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept. Funny I never saw the index method for jquery before.